# How can I calculate similarity between two strings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, similarity

I'm looking to assess similarity (including case) between two strings and give a value between 0 and 1.

I tried the Levenshtein distance implementation but it only gives integers and does not compare inner alphabets.

For e.g. comparing "ABCD" and "Abcd" gives distance of 3 and "AOOO" also gives a distance of 3 but clearly "Abcd" is better match than "AOOO".

So compared to "ABCD" I want "ABcd" to be most similar then "Abcd" then "AOOO" then "AOOOO"

I've also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157) but I am not looking for a variable length algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Try Levensthein distance with lower-case only strings perhaps ?

Comment: So, is AOOOBCD a better match than Abcd? I suspect your notion of "better" won't hold up fire very well.  Probably the best you can hope for is to rank them by some arbitray rules (e.g., first by Levenstein, second by number of case changes, etc.) and show a list to a user, whose notion of similar may not match yours.

Comment: @IraBaxter Nope "Abcd" will be a better match than "AOOOBCD"

Comment: This isn't really a programming (implementation) question. This is a question of design - design of a suitable similarity function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
double d = (LevenshteinDist(s, t) + LevenshteinDist(s.ToLower(), t.ToLower())) /
           2.0 * Math.Max(s.Length, t.Length);
```

If you want to give less importance to case differences than letter differences, you can give different weights to the terms

```
double d = (0.15*LevenshteinDist(s, t) + 
            0.35*LevenshteinDist(s.ToLower(), t.ToLower())) /
           Math.Max(s.Length, t.Length);
```

Note that the weights sum up to 0.5, thus makting the division by 2.0 obsolete.

Comment: Nice! should of thought of that

Comment: Levenshtein Distance in c#
https://gist.github.com/Davidblkx/e12ab0bb2aff7fd8072632b396538560

Answer (score 2):

Adapt Levenshtein Distance with a custom table T. Let the cost of insertion = 1. The cost of deletion also 1. Let T(c,d) denote the penalty of replacing c with d. T(c,c) should be = 0. T(c,d) should be <= 2.

Define Max(n,m) be the maximum theoretical distance of strings of length n and m. Obviously, Max(n,m) = n+m.

Define Distance(s,t) be the cost of changing s to t divided by Max(s,t). There you go.

Be careful in defining T so that the definition obeys distance axioms:

- Distance(s,s) = 0
- Distance(s,t) = Distance(t,s)
- Distance(s,t) <= Distance(s,u) + Distance(u,t)

Then it will be more useful in more situations.

Answer (score 2):

```
    bool check(string[] a, string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            if (s == a[i])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public double simi(string string1, string string2)
    {
        int sub1 = 0;
        int sub2 = 0;
        string[] sp1 = new string[string1.Length - 1];
        string[] sp2 = new string[string2.Length - 1];
        string[] sp3 = new string[string1.Length - 1];
        string[] sp4 = new string[string2.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string x = "";
            x = string1.Substring(i, 2);

            sp1[sub1] = x;
            ++sub1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < string2.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string x = "";
            x = string2.Substring(i, 2);
            sp2[sub2] = x;
            ++sub2;
        }


        int j = 0, k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sp1.Length; i++)
            if (check(sp3, sp1[i]) == true)
            {

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                sp3[j] = sp1[i];
                j++;

            }

        for (int i = 0; i < sp2.Length; i++)
            if (check(sp4, sp2[i]) == true)
            {

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                sp4[k] = sp2[i];
                k++;


            }

        Array.Resize(ref sp3, j);
        Array.Resize(ref sp4, k);

        Array.Sort<string>(sp3);
        Array.Sort<string>(sp4);

        int n = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < sp3.Length; i++)
        {

            if (check(sp4, sp3[i]))
            {

                n++;
            }


        }

        double resulte;

        int l1 = sp3.Length;
        int l2 = sp4.Length;

        resulte = ((2.0 * Convert.ToDouble(n)) / Convert.ToDouble(l1 + l2)) * 100;

        return resulte;
    }
```