# creating a document comparison software

Tags: java, php, python

I want to create an application that can determine if some text was copied between two documents by reading the text from the two documents and comparing them. I wanted to know if anyone had ever tried to do this and what was the best way of handling the same. If machine learning and natural language processing are involved: to what level?

Comment: lots of people have tried this.  turnitin.com is just one example.

Comment: wanted to check plagiarism by comparing the texts in the two documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [**Copyscape**](http://www.copyscape.com/) uses **4-grams** to help determine uniqueness.

These strings are referred to as [**N-Grams**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).

However, [**another SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/653165/1333791) linked to a [**language independent algo comparing bi-grams**](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html) on a character basis. It's already implemented in Java, which would help save time.

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques which rely purely on set-theoretic concepts

Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling  for a good start.