# Use gems with c-extensions in JRuby, or port them to Java?

Tags: jruby, fuzzy-search, ruby-c-extension, jruby-java-interop, mri

I'm doing a fuzzy match test between an input string and some previously entered strings. The test is performed live while typing.

I already have a shockingly accurate algorithm in place called [StrikeAMatch](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html), which [has been translated into many languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings). The fastest Ruby implementation I've found is [amatch](https://github.com/flori/amatch). However, it is incompatible with my JRuby environment [because it crunches data in a C extension](http://forum.ruby-portal.de/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=9053) that requires the C interpreter for Ruby (MRI). It's pretty fast though:

```
a = "Lorem ipsum dolor"
b = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante,"
puts Benchmark.measure {
  10000.times { a.pair_distance_similar(b) }
}
# => 0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.146347)
```

I hope I can avoid setting up an alternative environment. An alternative approach could be to try and port the original Java code [as suggested in the JRuby Wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DifferencesBetweenMriAndJruby#native-c-extensions). Not sure how to do that though.

Any ideas about how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is easy to implement.  For example, here's a quick implementation I wrote in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class StrikeAMatch {

    protected int numPairs(final String string) {
        return Math.max(0, string.length() - 1);
    }

    protected Map<String, Integer> pairs(final String string) {
        if (string.isEmpty()) {
            return new HashMap<>(0);
        }

        final Map<String, Integer> pairs = new HashMap(2 * numPairs(string));

        for (int i = 1, j = string.length(); i < j; i += 1) {
            final char a = string.charAt(i - 1);
            final char b = string.charAt(i);
            final String pair = String.format("%c%c", a, b);
            if (pairs.containsKey(pair)) {
                pairs.put(pair, 1 + pairs.get(pair));
            }
            else {
                pairs.put(pair, 1);
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }

    protected int intersectionSize(
            final Map<String, Integer> lhsPairs,
            final Map<String, Integer> rhsPairs) {
        final Set<String> lhsKeys = lhsPairs.keySet();
        final Set<String> rhsKeys = rhsPairs.keySet();
        final Set<String> pairIntersection = new HashSet<>(lhsKeys);
        pairIntersection.retainAll(rhsKeys);
        int sharedPairs = 0;
        for (final String pair : pairIntersection) {
            sharedPairs += Math.min(lhsPairs.get(pair), rhsPairs.get(pair));
        }
        return sharedPairs;
    }

    public double between(final String lhs, final String rhs) {
        if (lhs.isEmpty() && rhs.isEmpty()) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        final Map<String, Integer> lhsPairs = pairs(lhs.toUpperCase());
        final Map<String, Integer> rhsPairs = pairs(rhs.toUpperCase());
        return (2.0 * intersectionSize(lhsPairs, rhsPairs))
             / (numPairs(lhs) + numPairs(rhs));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final StrikeAMatch distance = new StrikeAMatch();
        for (final String lhs : args) {
            for (final String rhs : args) {
                System.out.printf("d(\"%s\", \"%s\") = [%.7f]%n",
                    lhs, rhs, distance.between(lhs, rhs));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even pad the first and last characters, to extend it to one-character or zero-character terms:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PaddedStrikeAMatch extends StrikeAMatch {

    protected int numPairs(final String string) {
        return string.length() + 1;
    }

    protected Map<String, Integer> pairs(final String string) {
        if (string.isEmpty()) {
            final Map<String, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<>(1);
            pairs.put("  ", 1);
            return pairs;
        }

        final Map<String, Integer> pairs = new HashMap(2 * numPairs(string));
        pairs.put(String.format(" %c", string.charAt(0)), 1);
        pairs.put(String.format("%c ", string.charAt(string.length() - 1)), 1);

        for (int i = 1, j = string.length(); i < j; i += 1) {
            final char a = string.charAt(i - 1);
            final char b = string.charAt(i);
            final String pair = String.format("%c%c", a, b);
            if (pairs.containsKey(pair)) {
                pairs.put(pair, 1 + pairs.get(pair));
            }
            else {
                pairs.put(pair, 1);
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final StrikeAMatch distance = new PaddedStrikeAMatch();
        for (final String lhs : args) {
            for (final String rhs : args) {
                System.out.printf("d(\"%s\", \"%s\") = [%.7f]%n",
                    lhs, rhs, distance.between(lhs, rhs));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To validate it, here are the examples proposed in the link you provided:

```
% java StrikeAMatch France French
d("France", "France") = [1.0000000]
d("France", "French") = [0.4000000]
d("French", "France") = [0.4000000]
d("French", "French") = [1.0000000]

% java StrikeAMatch Healed Sealed Healthy Heard Herded Help Sold
d("Healed", "Healed") = [1.0000000]
d("Healed", "Sealed") = [0.8000000]
d("Healed", "Healthy") = [0.5454545]
d("Healed", "Heard") = [0.4444444]
d("Healed", "Herded") = [0.4000000]
d("Healed", "Help") = [0.2500000]
d("Healed", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Sealed", "Healed") = [0.8000000]
d("Sealed", "Sealed") = [1.0000000]
d("Sealed", "Healthy") = [0.3636364]
d("Sealed", "Heard") = [0.2222222]
d("Sealed", "Herded") = [0.2000000]
d("Sealed", "Help") = [0.0000000]
d("Sealed", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Healthy", "Healed") = [0.5454545]
d("Healthy", "Sealed") = [0.3636364]
d("Healthy", "Healthy") = [1.0000000]
d("Healthy", "Heard") = [0.4000000]
d("Healthy", "Herded") = [0.1818182]
d("Healthy", "Help") = [0.2222222]
d("Healthy", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Heard", "Healed") = [0.4444444]
d("Heard", "Sealed") = [0.2222222]
d("Heard", "Healthy") = [0.4000000]
d("Heard", "Heard") = [1.0000000]
d("Heard", "Herded") = [0.4444444]
d("Heard", "Help") = [0.2857143]
d("Heard", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Herded", "Healed") = [0.4000000]
d("Herded", "Sealed") = [0.2000000]
d("Herded", "Healthy") = [0.1818182]
d("Herded", "Heard") = [0.4444444]
d("Herded", "Herded") = [1.0000000]
d("Herded", "Help") = [0.2500000]
d("Herded", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Help", "Healed") = [0.2500000]
d("Help", "Sealed") = [0.0000000]
d("Help", "Healthy") = [0.2222222]
d("Help", "Heard") = [0.2857143]
d("Help", "Herded") = [0.2500000]
d("Help", "Help") = [1.0000000]
d("Help", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Healed") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Sealed") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Healthy") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Heard") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Herded") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Help") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Sold") = [1.0000000]
```

... and here's the padded version:

```
% java PaddedStrikeAMatch France French
d("France", "France") = [1.0000000]
d("France", "French") = [0.4285714]
d("French", "France") = [0.4285714]
d("French", "French") = [1.0000000]

% java PaddedStrikeAMatch Healed Sealed Healthy Heard Herded Help Sold
d("Healed", "Healed") = [1.0000000]
d("Healed", "Sealed") = [0.7142857]
d("Healed", "Healthy") = [0.5333333]
d("Healed", "Heard") = [0.6153846]
d("Healed", "Herded") = [0.5714286]
d("Healed", "Help") = [0.3333333]
d("Healed", "Sold") = [0.1666667]
d("Sealed", "Healed") = [0.7142857]
d("Sealed", "Sealed") = [1.0000000]
d("Sealed", "Healthy") = [0.2666667]
d("Sealed", "Heard") = [0.3076923]
d("Sealed", "Herded") = [0.2857143]
d("Sealed", "Help") = [0.0000000]
d("Sealed", "Sold") = [0.3333333]
d("Healthy", "Healed") = [0.5333333]
d("Healthy", "Sealed") = [0.2666667]
d("Healthy", "Healthy") = [1.0000000]
d("Healthy", "Heard") = [0.4285714]
d("Healthy", "Herded") = [0.2666667]
d("Healthy", "Help") = [0.3076923]
d("Healthy", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Heard", "Healed") = [0.6153846]
d("Heard", "Sealed") = [0.3076923]
d("Heard", "Healthy") = [0.4285714]
d("Heard", "Heard") = [1.0000000]
d("Heard", "Herded") = [0.6153846]
d("Heard", "Help") = [0.3636364]
d("Heard", "Sold") = [0.1818182]
d("Herded", "Healed") = [0.5714286]
d("Herded", "Sealed") = [0.2857143]
d("Herded", "Healthy") = [0.2666667]
d("Herded", "Heard") = [0.6153846]
d("Herded", "Herded") = [1.0000000]
d("Herded", "Help") = [0.3333333]
d("Herded", "Sold") = [0.1666667]
d("Help", "Healed") = [0.3333333]
d("Help", "Sealed") = [0.0000000]
d("Help", "Healthy") = [0.3076923]
d("Help", "Heard") = [0.3636364]
d("Help", "Herded") = [0.3333333]
d("Help", "Help") = [1.0000000]
d("Help", "Sold") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Healed") = [0.1666667]
d("Sold", "Sealed") = [0.3333333]
d("Sold", "Healthy") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Heard") = [0.1818182]
d("Sold", "Herded") = [0.1666667]
d("Sold", "Help") = [0.0000000]
d("Sold", "Sold") = [1.0000000]
```

If you want to use it directly from JRuby, you need only to add `StrikeAMatch.class` to your `$CLASSPATH`, and within your script `require 'java'` followed by `java_import 'StrikeAMatch`:

```
require 'java'

java_import 'StrikeAMatch'

distance = StrikeAMatch.new
ARGV.each do |lhs|
  ARGV.each do |rhs|
    puts "d(\"#{lhs}\", \"#{rhs}\") = [#{distance.between(lhs, rhs)}]"
  end
end
```

To invoke it:

```
% jruby strike_a_match.rb France French
d("France", "France") = [1.0]
d("France", "French") = [0.4]
d("French", "France") = [0.4]
d("French", "French") = [1.0]
```

Comment: I'm speechless, thanks for this very thourough answer. I will spend the next few days trying to implement it. In terms of speed, how do you think this Java implementation compares to the C implementation? I can tell that a [pure Ruby implementation](https://github.com/threedaymonk/text/blob/master/lib/text/white_similarity.rb) is 17x slower than the `amatch` C implementation, so apparently the language to perform the string test makes a big difference.

Comment: Most of the performance difference will be due to the libraries' choices of algorithms and data structures.  Some of it also has to do with primitives versus objects, as Ruby has no primitives so your characters, etc. are all boxed (you don't choose Ruby for raw performance).  The implementation I've written boxes integers in the map values, so you would probably want to look into fastutil, which has an Object2IntMap type that maps to primitives integers.  There is also plenty of room for optimization if you want raw speed.  I will compare the C and Ruby implementations later.

Answer (score 0):

there's 2 ways you could approach this :

1. take the C ext code from the existing Ruby gem and port it to Java

... there are many examples of gems that have specific extensions for C-Ruby/JRuby e.g json/nokogiri

2. take a Java port, load the Java classes and use JRuby's Java integration