# SQL : how to treat similar sounding values as same in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a peculiar requirement in Oracle. 
There is a column in a table with different values but sounds similar for ex: Limited, Ltd, Ltd., Etc. But I need to treat these same and shouldn't treat as distinct values. 
I tried it with Decode as below but the catch here is the values are not known to us. Below is just an example.

```
Create table test_dup(col1 varchar2(25));

Insert into test_dup values('limited');
Insert into test_dup values('ltd.');
Insert into test_dup values('Inc');
Insert into test_dup values('incorporate');

Select distinct decode(col1, 'limited', 1, 'ltd.', 1, 'Inc', 2, 'incorporate', 2) from dual;
```

This works when the values are known but in my requirement, the values are unknown.

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance,
Savitha

Comment: You could use the `soundex` function to match up similar-sounding values.  Or, for a more powerful similarity method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings

Comment: Strictly from a database perspective; you will have to map each definition by the users. Without proper mapping, any data can mean anything. I believe a similar approach can be taken by using front end algo using fuzzy match but not through the back end.

Comment: @rd_nielsen, We tried it through Soundex but it didn't yield us the expected results accurately. We'll try to adopt the methods provided in the link you shared. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Isaiah3015, yes, we need it strictly from DB perspective. We won't be able to change the mappings now. We shall  try to adopt the methods provided by rd_nielson, if possible. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to do it through Oracle-SQL. It is through UTL_MATCH package.

SELECT utl_match.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY('LTD.','LIMITED') FROM DUAL;

Regards,
Savitha