# Is there a foolproof way of matching two similar string sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[This is the CSV in question.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEELxw3UqwePf_EBxXZqxcyG9arGJTH39n38acN2bBQ/edit?usp=sharing) I got this data from Extra History, which is a video series that talks about many historical topics through many mini-series, such as 'Rome: The Punic Wars', or 'Europe: The First Crusades' (in the CSV). Episodes in these mini-series are numbered #1 up to #6 (though Justinian Theodora has two series, the first numbered #1-#6, the second #7-#12).

I would like to do some statistical analysis on these mini-series, which entails sorting these numbered episodes (e.g. episodes #2-#6) into their appropriate series, [i.e. end result look something like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16f7gUx7HLQZn8hODwL0yVSAa7V3sx4Wr/view?usp=sharing); I can then easily automate sorting into the appropriate python list.

My python code matches the #2-#6 episodes to the #1 episode correctly 99% of the time, with only 1 big error in red, and 1 slight error in yellow (because the first episode of that series is #7, not #1). However, I get the nagging feeling that there is an easier and foolproof way since the strings are well organized, with regular patterns in their names. Is that possible? And can I achieve that with my current code, or should I change and approach it from a different angle?

```
    import csv

    eh_csv = '/Users/Work/Desktop/Extra History Playlist Video Data.csv'
    
    with open(eh_csv, newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
    
    
    import re
    series_first = []
    series_rest = []
    singles_music_lies = []
    all_episodes = []           #list of name of all episodes
    
    #seperates all videos into 3 non-overlapping list: first episodes of a series,
    #the other numbered episodes of the series, and singles/music/lies videos
    for video in data:
        
        all_episodes.append(video[0])
    
        #need regex b/c normall string search of #1 also matched (Justinian &) Theodora #10 
        if len(re.findall('\\b1\\b', video[0])) == 1:
            series_first.append(video[0])
        elif '#' not in video[0]:
            singles_music_lies.append(video[0])
        else:
            series_rest.append(video[0])
    
    
    
    #Dice's Coefficient
    #got from here; John Rutledge's answer with NinjaMeTimbers modification
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_bigrams(string):
        """
        Take a string and return a list of bigrams.
        """
        s = string.lower()
        return [s[i:i+2] for i in list(range(len(s) - 1))]
    
    def string_similarity(str1, str2):
        """
        Perform bigram comparison between two strings
        and return a percentage match in decimal form.
        """
        pairs1 = get_bigrams(str1)
        pairs2 = get_bigrams(str2)
        union  = len(pairs1) + len(pairs2)
        hit_count = 0
        for x in pairs1:
            for y in pairs2:
                if x == y:
                    hit_count += 1
                    pairs2.remove(y)
                    break
        return (2.0 * hit_count) / union
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    #only take couple words of the episode's names for comparison, b/c the first couple words are 99% of the 
    #times the name of the series; can't make too short or words like 'the, of' etc will get matched (now or
    #in future), or too long because will increase chance of superfluous match; does much better than w/o
    #limitting to first few words
    def first_three_words(name_string):
                                                           #eg ''.join vs ' '.join         
        first_three = ' '.join(name_string.split()[:5])  #-->'The Haitian Revolution' slightly worse
        #first_three = ''.join(name_string.split()[:5])  #--> 'TheHaitianRevolution', slightly better
        return first_three
    
    
    
    #compared given episode with all first videos, and return a list of comparison scores
    def compared_with_first(episode, series_name = series_first):
    
        episode_scores = []
        for i in series_name:
            x = first_three_words(episode)
            y = first_three_words(i)
            #comparison_score = round(string_similarity(episode, i),4)
            comparison_score = round(string_similarity(x,y),4)
            episode_scores.append((comparison_score, i))
    
        return episode_scores
    
    
    matches = []
    
    #go through video number 2,3,4 etc in a series and compare them with the first episode
    #of all series, then get a comparison score
    
    for episode in series_rest:
        scores_list = compared_with_first(episode)
        similarity_score = 0
        most_likely_match = []
    
        #go thru list of comparison scores returned from compared_with_first,
        #then append the currentepisode/highest score/first episode to 
        #most_likely_match; repeat for all non-first episodes
        for score in scores_list:
            if score[0] > similarity_score:
                similarity_score = score[0]
                most_likely_match.clear()       #MIGHT HAVE BEEN THE CRUCIAL KEY 
                most_likely_match.append((episode,score)) 
        matches.append(most_likely_match)
    
    
    final_match = []
    
    for i in matches:
        final_match.append((i[0][0], i[0][1][1], i[0][1][0]))
        #just to get output in desired presentation
    
    
    
    path = '/Users/Work/Desktop/'                   
    with open('EH Sorting Episodes.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for currentRow in final_match:
            csvwriter.writerow(currentRow)
            #print(currentRow)
```

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: All your lines have "Extra History". Is that always the case?

Comment: It seems there is no guarantee about anything in the input format...