# What algorithm maps each element from set A to it best match in set B?

Tags: c#, algorithm, string-matching

I have 2 sets of strings A and B.

I want to do something that seems similar to what a search engine might have to do to build an index for keyword searching, but the application is mapping entities from one dataset to another where the keys differ, but are similar.

**Update:** Since my sample data below seems to be throwing off the question, I pasted in the actual data at the end, not sure if its too long to help though.

```
    A            B
    -------      --------
    Foo          Foo
    Bar          Bar - US
    Bat          bat
    Bing         Bingo
    Zep          Zee
                 zepplin
                 Bars
```

I'd like to go through each item of A and match it to an item of B.

Result:

```
Foo -> Foo
Bar -> Bar - US
Bat -> bat
Bing -> bing
Zep -> zepplin
```

I'd like to know if there already are existing ways to accomplish this.  I recall once reading about Baysean something or other in the context of extracting a summary sentence from a paragraph, but I don't know if that can be applied.

I'm thinking it's going to have to have inputs that define some heuristics, but that seems to make it fairly complicated.

Sample of Real Data

```
declare @A table (Name varchar(500))
declare @B table (FullName varchar(500))
insert into @A values ('AccuQuote')
insert into @A values ('Adchemy')
insert into @A values ('Affiliate Marketing Solutions')
insert into @A values ('Affinitas GmbH')
insert into @A values ('Alliance Health Networks')
insert into @A values ('Allied Van Lines')
insert into @A values ('Ascentive')
insert into @A values ('Astroway')
insert into @A values ('Astroway EUR')
insert into @A values ('Astroway UK')
insert into @A values ('B2E Marketing ')
insert into @A values ('Babylon')
insert into @A values ('Be2')
insert into @A values ('BeClose')
insert into @A values ('Bid Cactus')
insert into @A values ('Bidz.com')
insert into @A values ('BigPoint')
insert into @A values ('Bloomspot')
insert into @A values ('Borderless')
insert into @A values ('Brands 4 Friends')
insert into @A values ('Build My Move')
insert into @A values ('Buywithme')
insert into @A values ('Carchex')
insert into @A values ('Career Education Corporation')
insert into @A values ('Chilay Leads')
insert into @A values ('ClubeFashion')
insert into @A values ('Cole Haan')
insert into @A values ('Digital Performance')
insert into @A values ('Digital Target')
insert into @A values ('dLife')
insert into @A values ('EliteMate')
insert into @A values ('Elogia')
insert into @A values ('Encore')
insert into @A values ('Eskupina/Cdate')
insert into @A values ('Experian')
insert into @A values ('Fandango')
insert into @A values ('Funstage')
insert into @A values ('Game Tap')
insert into @A values ('GameDuell GmbH')
insert into @A values ('Gaylord Security')
insert into @A values ('Geico (precise Auto Quote)')
insert into @A values ('Global Test Market / GMI Euro')
insert into @A values ('Gold Star Events')
insert into @A values ('Guthy-Renker LLC')
insert into @A values ('HealthPlanOne')
insert into @A values ('Hifficiency')
insert into @A values ('HLG Solutions')
insert into @A values ('HotChalk')
insert into @A values ('HP AU/NZ')
insert into @A values ('HP UK')
insert into @A values ('IMVU')
insert into @A values ('InnoGames')
insert into @A values ('InsWeb Corporation')
insert into @A values ('Internet Brands')
insert into @A values ('Internet Order/Pimsleur')
insert into @A values ('JAG Method')
insert into @A values ('Kid Robot')
insert into @A values ('LexisNexis')
insert into @A values ('Lieferheld GmbH')
insert into @A values ('Life Line Screening')
insert into @A values ('Lovefilm')
insert into @A values ('LoveFilm GBP')
insert into @A values ('Marathon Data Systems')
insert into @A values ('Maximiles')
insert into @A values ('Medizine')
insert into @A values ('Meetic')
insert into @A values ('Mercury Media')
insert into @A values ('Merkle')
insert into @A values ('Mighty Net')
insert into @A values ('MyCityDeal EUR')
insert into @A values ('MyCityDeal GBP')
insert into @A values ('NARS')
insert into @A values ('New Peak Media')
insert into @A values ('Next Level Entertainment')
insert into @A values ('NPD Group')
insert into @A values ('Nutrasource')
insert into @A values ('Offer Shot')
insert into @A values ('OneTechnologies')
insert into @A values ('Pipeline Success')
insert into @A values ('Quinstreet')
insert into @A values ('Quinstreet / Surehits')
insert into @A values ('Quoteshound')
insert into @A values ('Radley & Co')
insert into @A values ('Red Ventures')
insert into @A values ('RentTheRunway')
insert into @A values ('Research Now')
insert into @A values ('Saban')
insert into @A values ('Savingstar')
insert into @A values ('Scholastic')
insert into @A values ('Scorebig')
insert into @A values ('SD&P')
insert into @A values ('ServiceMaster Brands')
insert into @A values ('Shermans Travels')
insert into @A values ('Shoebuy.com/Bagsbuy.com/FloraFlora')
insert into @A values ('Simplyink- Private')
insert into @A values ('Source Interlink Media - Automotive.com')
insert into @A values ('Spark Networks')
insert into @A values ('Terra Matrix')
insert into @A values ('The LASIK Vision Institute, LLC')
insert into @A values ('The Scooter Store')
insert into @A values ('Tickets Now')
insert into @A values ('Totsy.com')
insert into @A values ('Trafford Consulting')
insert into @A values ('Tranzact Media')
insert into @A values ('Tree.com')
insert into @A values ('Unirush')
insert into @A values ('United Sample')
insert into @A values ('Universal McCann')
insert into @A values ('Vinyl Interactive')
insert into @A values ('Vistaprint')
insert into @A values ('Vistaprint US')
insert into @A values ('Zamano')
insert into @A values ('Aaron A. the Advertiser')
insert into @A values ('Age of Learning ')
insert into @A values ('BrainyBaby')
insert into @A values ('Chrome Bags')
insert into @A values ('Datamark')
insert into @A values ('default')
insert into @A values ('Dish System')
insert into @A values ('Eminata')
insert into @A values ('Emma Stine')
insert into @A values ('Everyday Health')
insert into @A values ('Gate 1 Travel')
insert into @A values ('Hebrew Senior Life')
insert into @A values ('Itt Tech ')
insert into @A values ('Jan pro of Austin ')
insert into @A values ('Jan pro of Sacramento ')
insert into @A values ('KGB')
insert into @A values ('KupiKupon')
insert into @A values ('Lotto Elite')
insert into @A values ('Optical Express')
insert into @A values ('Personalization Mall')
insert into @A values ('PrintPal')
insert into @A values ('Prodege LLC')
insert into @A values ('Sixt')
insert into @A values ('StayFriends')
insert into @A values ('Urban Rivals')
insert into @A values ('Wpromote')
insert into @A values ('Besser Betreut')
insert into @A values ('ConnectionEngine')
insert into @A values ('CouponCoupon')
insert into @A values ('Coupons.com')
insert into @A values ('Everything Legal')
insert into @A values ('Gamigo')
insert into @A values ('Legacy Learning')
insert into @A values ('NFIB')
insert into @A values ('Noatel')
insert into @A values ('Termbusters')
insert into @A values ('Tioga Downs')
insert into @A values ('Alice.com')
insert into @A values ('BeRuby')
insert into @A values ('Betreut')
insert into @A values ('BidRivals')
insert into @A values ('Eye Buy Now')
insert into @A values ('Globe Life')
insert into @A values ('JP Austin')
insert into @A values ('JP Sacramento')
insert into @A values ('Lumos Labs')
insert into @A values ('Marketing Craze')
insert into @A values ('Pinney Insurance')
insert into @A values ('Simple Tuition')
insert into @A values ('T33ZE')
insert into @A values ('Tax Defense')
insert into @A values ('Ultradiamond')
insert into @A values ('UltraDiamonds')
insert into @A values ('World Commerce')
insert into @A values ('Emma Stein')
insert into @A values ('EseMarketing')
insert into @A values ('Heritage Resorts and Hotels')
insert into @A values ('Jan Pro Austin ')
insert into @A values ('Jan Pro Sacramento')
insert into @A values ('Jelly Belly')
insert into @A values ('JRM Management')
insert into @A values ('Lead Click Media')
insert into @A values ('Lumosity')
insert into @A values ('Military.com')
insert into @A values ('MobiKlix')
insert into @A values ('Monster ')
insert into @A values ('Monster Worldwide')
insert into @A values ('Nielsen')
insert into @A values ('Progrexion')
insert into @A values ('Studs-up')
insert into @A values ('Webjuice')
insert into @A values ('YouGov')
insert into @A values ('Betterment')
insert into @A values ('Credit Sesame')
insert into @A values ('Cupid PLC')
insert into @A values ('DebtManagers')
insert into @A values ('Education Dynamics')
insert into @A values ('Envision/Accurix')
insert into @A values ('Fortune Builders')
insert into @A values ('Fosina Marketing')
insert into @A values ('Fubar')
insert into @A values ('InterCall')
insert into @A values ('MayYeung')
insert into @A values ('OHP Direct')
insert into @A values ('SCB Media')
insert into @A values ('SmartQuote')
insert into @A values ('Western Wats')
insert into @A values ('Yves Rocher')
insert into @A values ('Anyhouse Exterminators')
insert into @A values ('Assicurazione')
insert into @A values ('Bigdeal.com')
insert into @A values ('Credit.com')
insert into @A values ('Cross Digital UK')
insert into @A values ('Direct Partners')
insert into @A values ('Flightline UK')
insert into @A values ('Lifescript')
insert into @A values ('LightSpeed')
insert into @A values ('Little Star Media ')
insert into @A values ('Match.com')
insert into @A values ('NAPW')
insert into @A values ('Planet49')
insert into @A values ('T33ZE/Specs Optics/')
insert into @A values ('Target Direct')
insert into @A values ('Any House Exterminating services')
insert into @A values ('Bidooka')
insert into @A values ('Christophe  Danhier')
insert into @A values ('Direct Agents Creative ')
insert into @A values ('eCircle')
insert into @A values ('Ecombuffet')
insert into @A values ('Elite Clicks Media ')
insert into @A values ('Hebrew Seniorlife')
insert into @A values ('InternetOne')
insert into @A values ('Jan-Pro of Sacramento')
insert into @A values ('LEC Connect')
insert into @A values ('NewStream')
insert into @A values ('Platnium Y & E/ EZ Carpet')
insert into @A values ('Scorelluxe')
insert into @A values ('Sir Alistair Rai')
insert into @A values ('SmartDate EUR')
insert into @A values ('Afaze')
insert into @A values ('Defender Direct')
insert into @A values ('eCGlobal')
insert into @A values ('Entertainment Shopping')
insert into @A values ('Gold Clerk')
insert into @A values ('HP DE')
insert into @A values ('Insurance Agents')
insert into @A values ('Insurance-ITSOL')
insert into @A values ('Kelly Brady')
insert into @A values ('Midasplayer')
insert into @A values ('Prime Gaming')
insert into @A values ('Sign-post')
insert into @A values ('Singlesnet')
insert into @A values ('SmartDate USD')
insert into @A values ('Zoosk')
insert into @A values ('2Tor')
insert into @A values ('Adaptive')
insert into @A values ('Art.com')
insert into @A values ('Direct Brands')
insert into @A values ('EZ Carpet')
insert into @A values ('First Impression Interactive')
insert into @A values ('Funspire')
insert into @A values ('GMI')
insert into @A values ('Jan Pro Raleigh')
insert into @A values ('Mindspark')
insert into @A values ('PAMLI Capital Management')
insert into @A values ('Reliaquote')
insert into @A values ('Runge Moving')
insert into @A values ('Scholastic - Creative ')
insert into @A values ('Web2Carz')
insert into @B values ('Affinitas GmbH')
insert into @B values ('Assicurazione.it S.r.l.')
insert into @B values ('Astroway Ltd - Unit 2605')
insert into @B values ('Astroway Ltd - Unit 2605 UK')
insert into @B values ('Astrum Online Entertainment/ Mail. RU')
insert into @B values ('be2 GmbH')
insert into @B values ('BeRuby/ Maruby Internet')
insert into @B values ('Betreut.de')
insert into @B values ('Brands 4 Friends')
insert into @B values ('Clube Fashion')
insert into @B values ('Complaint Handling Services Limited')
insert into @B values ('Cross Digital/INTERACTIVE AVENUE')
insert into @B values ('Digital North - DNA')
insert into @B values ('Digital Performance')
insert into @B values ('Direct Agents - EURO')
insert into @B values ('Direct Agents - GBP')
insert into @B values ('Direct Agents, Inc. - US Transfer')
insert into @B values ('eCircle GmbH')
insert into @B values ('Ecircle Ltd. UK')
insert into @B values ('eProspects')
insert into @B values ('Eskupina/Cdate')
insert into @B values ('Everything Legal')
insert into @B values ('Flightline.co.uk')
insert into @B values ('Frogster Online Gaming GmbH')
insert into @B values ('FunStage')
insert into @B values ('GameDuell - Especial')
insert into @B values ('GameDuell GmbH')
insert into @B values ('Gamigo AG')
insert into @B values ('Global Test Market / GMI')
insert into @B values ('Greentube I.E.S. GmbH/Funstage')
insert into @B values ('Groupon-Especial')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:AE - Groupon FZ-LLC')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:AT - Groupon AT GmbH')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:AU - Stardeal Pty Ltd')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:BE - Groupon S.P.R.L')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:BR - Groupon Servi‡os Digitais Ltda.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:CH - Groupon CH GmbH')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:ES - Groupon Spain SL')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:FI - CityDeal Oy')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:FR - Groupon France SAS')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:IE - Groupon-CityDeal Ireland Ltd.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:IL - Grouper Social Shopping Ltd.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:IN - Friday Media (P) Ltd.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:IT - Groupon S.r.l.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:NL - Groupon B.V.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:NO - CityDeal AS')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:NZ - Groupon New Zealand Ltd')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:PH - Beeconomic Philippines Inc.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:PL - Groupon Sp. z o.o.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:RO - Groupon Internet SRL')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:SE - MyCityDeal AB')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:SG - Beeconomic Singapore Pte. Ltd.')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:TR - Groupon Bilisim Pazarlama Hizmetleri')
insert into @B values ('Groupon Gmbh:ZA - Twangoo South Africa Pty (LTD)')
insert into @B values ('Grumbl Media')
insert into @B values ('Heritage Resorts and Hotels')
insert into @B values ('Hifficiency/AdRoi')
insert into @B values ('HP DE')
insert into @B values ('HP Enterprise Services UK Ltd')
insert into @B values ('HP Enterprise Services UK Ltd:HP AU')
insert into @B values ('InnoGames')
insert into @B values ('Just a Game GmbH')
insert into @B values ('KGB UK')
insert into @B values ('King.com')
insert into @B values ('Lieferheld')
insert into @B values ('LIGHTSPEED RESEARCH')
insert into @B values ('Little Star Media')
insert into @B values ('LOVEFiLM Deutschland GmbH 1')
insert into @B values ('LOVEFiLM International Limited')
insert into @B values ('Marketing Craze')
insert into @B values ('Maximiles UK')
insert into @B values ('Meetic')
insert into @B values ('MobiKlix Ltd')
insert into @B values ('MoneyNet/Sterling Business Consultants')
insert into @B values ('MyCityDeal')
insert into @B values ('MyTheresa.com')
insert into @B values ('NeoPoint Technologies')
insert into @B values ('Next Idea GMBH')
insert into @B values ('Nivoria Online Marketing Agency')
insert into @B values ('Noatel')
insert into @B values ('Optical Express')
insert into @B values ('Optical Express - DE')
insert into @B values ('Psychonomics')
insert into @B values ('SCBmedia')
insert into @B values ('SD&P Online Media Group')
insert into @B values ('Shoebuy UK')
insert into @B values ('Skillstar.com')
insert into @B values ('Smartdate')
insert into @B values ('Stay Friends')
insert into @B values ('Survey Sampling International-GBP payment')
insert into @B values ('Survey Sampling International / SSI')
insert into @B values ('Terra Matrix Media')
insert into @B values ('Twistbox Entertainment/AMV Holding Ltd.')
insert into @B values ('Urban Rivals')
insert into @B values ('Virtual World Direct Limited.')
insert into @B values ('Vistaprint-Germany')
insert into @B values ('VISTAPRINT ESPA¥A S.L')
insert into @B values ('Zamano')
insert into @B values ('ZED Germany GmbH')
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for levenstein (sp?) distance

Comment: You couldn't change your examples could you, so that the values on the left are actually in set A and the values on the right are in set B? It's doing my head in.

Comment: The more i interact with other programmers on SO the more i think i developed a less-than-ideal way of thinking over the years... i honestly don't understand what the confusion is, but i do not doubt it exists at all

Comment: Eg, you show Zip and zipplin in results, but neither appears in A or B.  Also, you don't say why Bar goes to Bar - US instead of to Bars. -1

Comment: thanks. i'll clarify.  zipplin is totally my bad - its a typo.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972289/fast-dynamic-fuzzy-search-over-100k-strings-in-c-sharp/5972496#5972496).

You need to define what you want to do before you try to find something that can do it.

What counts as "a match"?

- If it's just a case-insensitive `CONTAINS` then it is trivial.
- If you need to consider / exclude certain punction then simply strip it from each dataset for comparison purposes
- Matching abbreviations? You might make a lookup that maps `inc` to `incorporated`, for example (you seem to be working with company names)
- Spelling mistakes - look into Levenstein and other [Edit distance algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)
- Phonetics / 'sounds like' - look into SoundEx and other [Phonetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm)

Do you prefer false positives, or false negatives? How accurate do you need to be - is this a first pass filter after which a small number can be done manually, or is this an automated process that needs to be correct every time?

It can be as complicated as you want it to be.

Comment: thanks - you did a good job of verbalizing/validating what my instincts about the answer basically were... it falls into category of a one-time task where I'm attempting to get the best starting point before i hand the work off to an intern to correct manually