# Compare string similarity

Tags: c#, .net, string, algorithm, string-comparison

What is the best way to compare two strings to see how similar they are?

Examples:

```
My String
My String With Extra Words
```

Or

```
My String
My Slightly Different String
```

What I am looking for is to determine how similar the first and second string in each pair is. I would like to score the comparison and if the strings are similar enough, I would consider them a matching pair.

Is there a good way to do this in C#?

Comment: Levenshtein edit distance, Soundex, and Hamming distance all do this in different ways.  You'll need to better define your metric before you can find an implementation.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling into this question: consider https://github.com/DanHarltey/Fastenshtein

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for-c

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
static class LevenshteinDistance
{
    public static int Compute(string s, string t)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
                return 0;
            return t.Length;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            return s.Length;
        }

        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // initialize the top and right of the table to 0, 1, 2, ...
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++);
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++);

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
                int min1 = d[i - 1, j] + 1;
                int min2 = d[i, j - 1] + 1;
                int min3 = d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost;
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(min1, min2), min3);
            }
        }
        return d[n, m];
    }
}
```

Comment: This was going to be my answer. The Damereau-Levenshein Distance algorithm calculates the number of letter additions, subtractions, substitutions, and transpositions (swaps) necessary to convert one string to another. The lower the score, the more similar they are.

Comment: It should be noted that this approach is very memory-intensive even for medium-sized strings. There’s an easy fix that requires only `min(n, m) + 1` extra memory.

Comment: This worked great. Luckily all of my strings are very short (50 characters or less), so it processes very quickly for me.

Comment: Faster implementation is here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120526085419/http://www.merriampark.com/ldjava.htm.  Some tests I was running went from 30-50 seconds to 8-10 seconds.

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman Instead of the full matrix, only store the previous column vector, as well as the single field corresponding to the previous row of the current coloumn, `prev` (hence +1). At a given row *i*, all values from 0–(*i*-1) in the vector correspond to the updated values. That is, the assignment in the loop reads `prev = d[i]; d[i] = Math.Min(…);`. It’s worth noting that this is *better* than the implementation you’ve linked to in your updated comment.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone was wondering what the C# equivalent of what @FrankSchwieterman posted is:

```
public static int GetDamerauLevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(s, "String Cannot Be Null Or Empty");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(t, "String Cannot Be Null Or Empty");
    }

    int n = s.Length; // length of s
    int m = t.Length; // length of t

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    int[] p = new int[n + 1]; //'previous' cost array, horizontally
    int[] d = new int[n + 1]; // cost array, horizontally

    // indexes into strings s and t
    int i; // iterates through s
    int j; // iterates through t

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        char tJ = t[j - 1]; // jth character of t
        d[0] = j;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int cost = s[i - 1] == tJ ? 0 : 1; // cost
            // minimum of cell to the left+1, to the top+1, diagonally left and up +cost                
            d[i] = Math.Min(Math.Min(d[i - 1] + 1, p[i] + 1), p[i - 1] + cost);
        }

        // copy current distance counts to 'previous row' distance counts
        int[] dPlaceholder = p; //placeholder to assist in swapping p and d
        p = d;
        d = dPlaceholder;
    }

    // our last action in the above loop was to switch d and p, so p now 
    // actually has the most recent cost counts
    return p[n];
}
```

Comment: I think that s or t could be null or empty as then the difference would be 100% or none if both are the same. I would also do an equal to see if they are the same right at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

I am comparing two sentences like this

```
string[] vs = string1.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-', '/', '(', ')' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] vs1 = string2.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-', '/', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


vs.Intersect(vs1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count();
```

Intersect gives you a set of identical word lists , I continue by looking at the count and saying if it is more than 1, these two sentences contain similar words.