# Matching a variable with an value in excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, ip, subnet

I have a code where I enter an Ip address and I want it to find its closing matching subnet from the spreadsheet I have attached that has a whole range of subnets.

Basically, take the value inputted find the closest value in a cell in the spreadsheet and print it to console. Here is my code, I commented out a few lines so I could test out if the spreadsheet was linked properly. There are only 2 columns in the excel sheet. Column A and B. The cells go all the way down a few thousand rows.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Investigations
{
    class Program
    {





        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;
            string str;


            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
            Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName);


            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Subnets.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;
            Excel.XlFindLookIn xlValues;
            Excel.XlLookAt xlPart;

            /* int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
          int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
          string[] headers = new string[colCount + 1];
          for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
          {
              headers[cCnt] = (Convert.ToString((xlRange.Cells[1, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));

          }

          for (rCnt = 2; rCnt <= rowCount; rCnt++)
          {
              for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
              {

                  str = (Convert.ToString((xlRange.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));
                  Console.Write(headers[cCnt]);
                  Console.Write(" ");
                  Console.WriteLine(str);

              }

              Console.WriteLine("----------------");


          }
      }





 }



      }

  */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lemme get this straight, you have an ip address and you want to find it in the excel file ?

Comment: Yes it's a subnet range but pretty much would read the same as an IP

Comment: Do you know the sheet name and the column names of the excel file ?

Comment: Yes I do know the names

Comment: try convering ip addresses to string if its not, then use this algorythm : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944056/c-sharp-compare-string-similarity