# How can I check the input if it's nearly same or not?

Tags: c#, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any Fuzzy Search or String Similarity Functions libraries written for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for-c)

I need to check the similarity of input value -which one user entered- to our records.

```
12345 vs 1234
12345 vs 13245
Robert vs Robret
```

etc...

In short; I need to calculate the similarity and tolerate the input in some ratio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google shows me [this](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2009/01/26/string-similarity-and-extension-methods.aspx)

Comment: There is a sample project which one contains Levenstein distance & some other cool algorithms including String.Similarity() in percent.

Answer (score 3):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a string similarity algorithm you could use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for an [Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm.