# Why can I run SSIS Fuzzy Grouping from Visual Studio but not the deployed package?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, ssis, fuzzy-search

I have written an SSIS package to create a Fuzzy Grouping. I can run it from Visual Studio targeting any of my servers and it will run without any problem. If I try to run the dtsx by remoting to any of those servers, I get the PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW error when the Fuzzy Grouping component executes.

I'm running SQL Server 2005 Standard on all servers. I've read that SQL Server 2005 Enterprise is necessary to make use of Fuzzy Grouping and some other components. That fits with the error message, but if this is true why does it work from Visual Studio?

Thank you.

EDIT: Are there other methods out there to create a fuzzy grouping? Perhaps someone with experience with SSIS components could say whether creating a similar component would be an option?

Comment: What version of BIDS do you have installed? Also, is SSIS installed and running on the servers?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2005 for my SSIS development. SSIS is installed and the service is running on each server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have correctly identified, [Fuzzy Grouping transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345128%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is an Enterprise Edition (or greater) feature.

The reason for Enterprise level features being available is that MS exposes the full set of options for the developer edition which is what Visual Studio is basically using.

If @Aaron Bertrand chimes in on this thread, I think he has a connect issue requesting that VS allows you to develop against the target edition so people don't get stuck developing Enterprise Edition level solutions for Standard edition feature set.

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to develop my own SSIS component that would perform a similar function?

Comment: I haven't had much reason to use the Fuzzy components but I'm certain you could roll your own. It'd be a matter of finding a sufficiently good text matching algorithm (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for-c) and then rolling that into a component. Should be fine keeping it all in memory, assuming you aren't running massively large sets through it.