# Visual Studio Community 2015 - No Fuzzy Components

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2015.  I have also installed the Integration Services features from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383 (see point two).  I am now able to create an integration services project.  There are components available such as: Data Flow Task; For Loop Container etc.

However, there is no Fuzzy Lookup or Fuzzy Grouping.  Why is this?

I only have SQL Server Express installed on this PC.  Do I have to have SQL Server Enterprise? This seems to suggest that I do not: [Why can I run SSIS Fuzzy Grouping from Visual Studio but not the deployed package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571974/why-can-i-run-ssis-fuzzy-grouping-from-visual-studio-but-not-the-deployed-packag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fuzzy Lookup and Fuzzy Group components will only show up in the SSIS Toolbox panel when you are inside a Data Task.  They are not relevant (and therefore not offered) when you are in Control Flow view of the package.

Comment: Thanks. I realised this shortly after posting. I was going to delete but will leave now.